# performFetchWithCompletionHandler does the http fetch must be made in the main thread or in a background thread?

Tags: ios

in performFetchWithCompletionHandler, does all http request must be done in the main ui thread or in background thread ?

Comment: Don't do this on the main thread. Do it on background thread

Comment: yes but what i don't understand is what is the purpose to do it in the background thread if i must in anycase call the completionHandler with the result? so i must wait in the main thread the result ?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the HTTP requests in the Background Thread. If you receive some kind of data to populate your dataSource, then you should put the `.reloadData()` in your Main Thread.

Supposing you're using a `tableView` to show your results, you may place this code in your `completionHandler:`

**Swift 3:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This part of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html) may give you a better explanation about this topic.

Comment: yes but what i don't understand is what is the purpose to do it in the background thread if i must in anycase call the completionHandler with the result? so i must wait in the main thread the result ?

Comment: Because one of the responsibilities of the main thread is to render the UI. Usually any IO request (such as HTTP request) is slower than a frame render (which should happen every 16.7ms in order to get 60FPS). That is why you only call the main thread when the data is ready.

Comment: yes but when the app is in background, their is no need to render anything. anyway you didn't say, if i do the http request in background thread, when i will call the completionHandler ?

Comment: Background thread doesn't mean your app is running in background. The `completionHandler` will be called as soon as the request finishes. The framework will be the one responsible for calling the `completionHandler` when the request finishes.